# Linq Query Optimization

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda, linq-to-xml

How can I optimize this query & convert into lambda ?

```
XElement xde = new XElement("Elements", (from a in rootElement.Elements("Class")
                   where a.Attribute("Location").Value.Equals("FirstFloor") 
                   select (from b in a.Elements("Subject")
                           where b.Attribute("Notify").Value.Equals("001")
                           select b.Elements())));
```

Comment: Dude seriously http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: What do want optimized? Readability? Performance? Defensiveness? Also, make sure to explain what problems you currently have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of performance, I think your query can't be optimized.

Hoewever you can make it more readable repacing `Equals` by `==` and removing an unecessary `select`

```
XElement xde =
        new XElement("Elements", (from a in rootElement.Elements("Class")
                                  where a.Attribute("Location").Value == "FirstFloor"
                                  from b in a.Elements("Subject")
                                  where b.Attribute("Notify").Value == "001"
                                  select b.Elements()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply case node to `string` instead of reading node's value. Thus you will avoid exceptions if there is missing attribute in your xml. Also I suggest you to use range variable names which correspond to element name (better readability):

```
XElement xde =
    new XElement("Elements",  
         from c in rootElement.Elements("Class")
         where (string)c.Attribute("Location") == "FirstFloor"
         from s in c.Elements("Subject")
         where (string)s.Attribute("Notify") == "001"
         select s.Elements());
```

---

Consider also using XPath (all query will fit one line):

```
new XElement("Elements", rootElement
 .XPathSelectElements("Class[@Location='FirstFloor']/Subject[@Notify='001']/*"));
```

---

Lambda (you wanted method syntax also):

```
new XElement("Elements", 
    rootElement.Elements("Class")
               .Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("Location") == "FirstFloor")
               .Elements("Subject")
               .Where(s => (string)s.Attribute("Notify") == "001")
               .Elements());
```